# Ajax `appendTo` replaces the existing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to submit some form data to `Servlet` using `JQuery` and retrieve the `Servlet` response from the same `JQuery`. Please have a look at the below code.

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Feb 23, 2015, 8:18:52 PM
    Author     : Yohan
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var form = $('#customItemForm');
  function formSubmit(){

 $.ajax({
     url:'SampleServlet',
     data: $("#customItemForm").serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
            $("#results").text(data);

            var $textbox = $('<input type=text>').appendTo($('<div>')).appendTo($('#results')); 
            $textbox.attr("id",data);

            //alert($textbox.attr("id"));
    }
});
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="SampleServlet" id="customItemForm"  onsubmit="formSubmit(); return false;">
    Name <input type="text" name="name">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
        <br>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code in JQuery section, I am trying to read the value I got from servlet, create a `Text Input` in a DIV. My expectation was if I click the "Submit" button twice, then 2 text boxes; if I click the submit button thrice, then 3 text boxes and so on. Unfortunatly it is not happening here. Only one text box appear, all the time, replacing the previous one.

How can I fix this?

Comment: $("#results").text(data); <- remove this and it should work

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: OK, but I need to display the data too?

Comment: ahhh i get it sorry, replace it with $("#results").append(data);

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Yes. I mean I need to display the value coming from `data` too.

Comment: where are you trying to show this data?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: infront of every textbox. Like `Label`

Comment: then replace $("#results").text(data); with $("#results").append(data); -> then look-up how to add elements so you can put it inside a label - above should at least get you where you can add multiple items - you were over-riding the content with .text()

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Cool. Please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
 url:'SampleServlet',
 data: $("#customItemForm").serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
        $("#results").text(data); //replace with $("#results").append(data)

        var $textbox = $('<input type=text>').appendTo($('<div>')).appendTo($('#results')); 
        $textbox.attr("id",data);

        //alert($textbox.attr("id"));
}
});
}
```

you need to make the change above as .text() replaces the existing data in the div (so the previous run you did gets over-written)